# Generate the .bat file that will copy the selected lines from the .bat file (within .bat file) to another text file

Tags: batch-file, dos

```
@echo off
:start
cls
Title Like or unlike
:1
echo.
set/p _file=output file name:
echo.
echo select the type
echo (1)like. (2)unlike
echo.
set/p _num=enter your option:
if %_num%==1 goto Like
if %_num%==2 goto Unlike
:Like
echo.
COPY the below lines to "%_file%"
The land is beautiful
I wanna stay here
etc........
etc........
exit
:unlike
echo.
COPY the below lines to "%_file%"
The land is ugly
I hate this land
exit
```

I want to creat the .bat file that will copy the selected lines from the .bat file (within .bat file) to another text file

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo OFF
setlocal
:start
CLS
Title Like or unlike
:1
echo.
set/p _file=output file name:
echo.
echo select the type
echo (1)like. (2)unlike
echo.
set/p _num=enter your option:
if %_num%==1 CALL :show Like&GOTO :eof
if %_num%==2 CALL :show UnLike&GOTO :eof

ECHO BAD OPTION
GOTO :EOF

:show
SET "out="
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1*" %%i IN ("%~dpnx0") DO (
IF /i %%i==exit SET "OUT="
IF DEFINED out >>"%_file%" echo %%i %%j
IF /i %%i==:%1 SET OUT=Y
)
GOTO :eof


:Like
The land is beautiful
I wanna stay here
etc........
etc........
exit
:unlike
The land is ugly
I hate this land
exit
```

Here's a starter. It isn't perfect. Note that `%~dpnx0` (or `%~f0`) is the drive path name extension of the 0'th batch parameter, which is the batch file itself

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(Echo The land is beautiful
echo I wanna stay here
echo etc........ 
echo etc........  
)>"%_file%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the lines as below

```
Echo The land is beautiful >> %_file%
echo I wanna stay here  >> %_file%
echo etc........  >> %_file%
echo etc........  >> %_file%
```